# How to center buttons with styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styles, styled-components

Can't figure out how to center 2 buttons *horizontally* with `styled-components`.

Below is my code.
Tried many ways to center, but didn't work.

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const HomeStyles = styled.div`
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: royalblue;
  }

  button {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: royalblue;
  }
`

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <HomeStyles>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <button>Button1</button>
      <button>Button2</button>
    </HomeStyles>
  )
}
```

**UPDATE**: I need to center buttons horizontally

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `flexbox` on parent element?

```
const HomeStyles = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  ....
`;

const ButtonsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

    <HomeStyles>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <ButtonsWrapper>
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
      </ButtonsWrapper>
    </HomeStyles>
```

[image: Edit Q-64852902-flexbox]

Comment: Thanks, but it's placing buttons vertically. I want buttons stay horizontal.

Comment: So wrap your buttons with `flex-direction` row